# Difference between ThirdParty Library ,Library , SDK,API AND framework?

Tags: swift

I am a iOS developer . I do not understand properly use to Library , SDK,API AND framework . Please anyone help that and shortly description and given any Example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I know this is not Q&A for "How to become IOS Developer" ; this answer may not receive up-vote and get some flags but i will try to help you.*

Try Cocoapods - https://cocoapods.org/
Read this:- https://www.raywenderlich.com/259-top-10-libraries-for-ios-developers

*Understand the basic of Swift Programming language, learn the basic syntax and OOP,*

*Initially you really don't need Library, SDK, API AND framework to build a project.

"libraries solve such a vast range of problems and no two are alike, it’s difficult to make logical comparisons and rank them in order of best to worst"*
Fortunately, *CocoaPods*, a popular *Swift* and *Objective-C* dependency manager, collects anonymous stats when users install packages.